# How to use PHP routing script in azure?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, reroute

I am currently running a inbuilt server and i want to transfer it to azure. At the moment I run the server with the following command

```
php -S localhost:8000 route.php
```

where route.php is my routing script which deals with all my requests. I have looked though the application setting in azure and I cant seem to find the required setting.

Comment: I have used a htaccess file to redirect the traffic to the php script

Comment: The file is actually a web.config because it runs on a window system I will post the config file as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web.config can be used to modify to the request before it is processed by the server. Therefore the following script can be used to push the traffic to the routing script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/route.php?url={R:1}" />
        </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The match and action parameters each regular expressions so can be modified for advanced routing

Answer (score 1):

PHP applications running on Azure Web Apps are hosted on IIS, and if I haven't misunderstood, you are using `route.php` as the entrance of your application.

You can configure the **Default documents** under Application settings blade on Azure portal,
[image]
set the `route.php` at the first place, then, when the request comes in, the IIS will find the pages one by one under the dufault document list, to handle the request.

Comment: Wouldn't that deliver a different route.php for each folder?  I think the OP is asking for forced traffic regardless of URL even for pages/paths that don't exist.